# React Router 404 page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am currently experiencing some issues regarding react router displaying of 404 not found-pages. This is the code I have so far:

```
 <Route path="/home" component={Home} exact={true}/>
 <Route path="/admin/forgot-password" component={AdminResetPassword} exact={true}/>
 <Authentication path="/admin/welcome" component={AdminWelcome} exact={true}/>
 <Authentication path="/admin/dashboard" component={AdminDashboard} exact={true}/>
```

However, if I try to do something like this:

```
<Route path="/home" component={Home} exact={true}/>
<Route path="/admin/forgot-password" component={AdminResetPassword} exact={true}/>
<Route path="*" component={Page404}/>
<Authentication path="/admin/welcome" component={AdminWelcome} exact={true}/>
<Authentication path="/admin/dashboard" component={AdminDashboard} exact={true}/>
```

The ting is, it works - but only for the pages that is not wrapped in authentication. In other words, if I was to try to navigate to an admin page, it just says 404 page not found. How would I fix this?

Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Are these in a `<Switch />`?

Comment: Can you mark this as correct if it helped?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `<Switch />`:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/home" component={Home} exact={true}/>
    <Route path="/admin/forgot-password" component={AdminResetPassword} exact={true}/>
    <Authentication path="/admin/welcome" component={AdminWelcome} exact={true}/>
    <Authentication path="/admin/dashboard" component={AdminDashboard} exact={true}/>
    <Route component={Page404}/>
</Switch>
```

If none of the paths before the last one match, the `Page404` will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from **React Router v6**, ["Not Found" Routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#not-found-routes) can be used to achieve this

##### Syntax

`<Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />`

##### Example

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
  <Route index element={<SneakerGrid />} />
  <Route path="/sneakers/:id" element={<SneakerView />} />
 
  <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />

</Routes>
```

Comment: thank you for keeping this discussion up to date :)